# Why is Google Analytics providing data when the tracking code is not yet even in place?

Tags: analytics

I think some other website is using the Google Analytics ID of one of our websites. I recently set up a new Analytics property for a new site but have not yet put the tracking codes in place. Then when I checked our Analytics earlier today, the new property is already reporting visits. How come?

Probably someone hacked our Google Analytics ID. But then we haven't even placed the codes on site so I'm not sure if this is the case. Am I missing something (probably due to a filter set up)?

And if some other website is indeed using our Google Analytics ID, is there a way for me to trace these sites?

I just configured our Analytics to monitor visits that only involve our hostname so hopefully this will solve the issue onwards. But still, are there other possible reasons?

Comment: Waht type of traffic is showing up?  There have been issues of referral spam lately - check the event report?  IF its stuff like "free-online-seo" then its spam.

Comment: @MarkeD 80% of the traffic is referral while 20% is direct. Referrals came from sites that seem like spam. But still, what about the 20% direct traffic? Also, how did they get a hold of our Analytics ID when we haven't even placed it on the site? (although I'm not really sure if they got hold of our ID to be able to screw our Analytics data)

Comment: Spammers at the moment seem to be sending traffic to randomly generated UA codes.  The direct traffic is probably the same but they haven't included a referrer to show up in the report.  When you actually launch, you can put a filter on your reports to take it out, here is a example: https://brianclifton.com/blog/2015/05/29/removing-referral-spam/

Comment: @MarkeD This is a very useful resource. I already implemented the hostname filter but will definitely look into the other tips. Thanks!